# How does block retain local objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

According to the Apple documentation

> When a block is copied, it creates strong references to object
>   variables used within the block. If you use a block within the
>   implementation of a method:
>
> If you access an instance variable by reference, a strong reference is
>   made to self; If you access an instance variable by value, a strong
>   reference is made to the variable.

I want to understand how a block manages to do this internally. How does it allocate memory for these objects and how are they referenced later in case of a block callback.

Answer (score 0):

When a block is copied, it creates strong references to object variables used within the block. If you use a block within the implementation of a method:

If you access an instance variable by reference, a strong reference is made to self;
If you access an instance variable by value, a strong reference is made to the variable.
I think you can read [block and variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) and [block introduce](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Comment: Yes, I have read that. I want to know how does a block do that internally. How does it allocate memory for these objects and how does it reference it?

Comment: This thing may be done in the compiler, block is a syntax unit, in compiler, it may output a static function ,in the function it retain the outside variable.

Comment: For the answer to that, @tbag, see the question I've linked. It explains exactly how Blocks are implemented.